# How 'broken down' can Polymer modules be before they start to hinder performance?

Tags: polymer, web-component, modularity, http2

From what I understand, sending a request from a HTTP 2 enabled client to a HTTP 2 enabled server means that multiple files can be pushed back to the client in the response, and has now meant that 'breaking down' HTML files into more module pieces no longer causes the same performance penalty as it once did.

This is really great.

However, with this in mind is there a way to calculate how 'broken down' Polymer's modules can be before they do start to hinder performance? And by 'hinder performance', I mean the bytes used up by the typical boilerplate code when writing a module. Here's an example of that code in a style module:

```
<dom-module id="typography-classes">
  <template>
    <style>
      h1 { font-size: 3rem; }
      h2 { font-size: 2rem; }
      h3 { font-size: 1rem; }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Let's say I want to break this down further because not every module importing this will use all the header tags:

```
<dom-module id="h1-class">
  <template>
    <style>
      h1 { font-size: 3rem; }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="h2-class">
  <template>
    <style>
      h2 { font-size: 2rem; }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<dom-module id="h3-class">
  <template>
    <style>
      h3 { font-size: 1rem; }
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Does this hinder performance at this level of modularity? And if so, are there any guidelines on how far modules can be 'broken down' to before they hinder performance?